# Check for page refresh or close with jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looking to check if a page has been refreshed or closed with jQuery or javascript.

What I have currently is I have some database values that I want to delete if the user either navigates away or refreshes the page.

I am using AJAX calls to delete the values.

Right now, I have the following code:

The handler:

```
window.beforeunload = cleanUp;
```

The `cleanUp()` method:

```
function cleanUp() {
    // Check to see if it's an actual page change.
    if(myActualLeave) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/cleanup",
            data: { id: myLocalId },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(myLocalId + " got removed from the database.");
            }
        });
    }

    // Reset the flag, so it can be checked again.
    myActualLeave = true;
}
```

Where `myActualLeave` is a flag that I set to false when AJAX calls are made, so they don't trigger the `beforeunload` handler.

The problem I am running into is that when I click a link on my page, so for instance a link to Google, the `window.beforeunload` doesn't trigger. I may have a misunderstanding of this, but I have tried using jQuery's `$(window).unload(...);` and the `onbeforeunload` trigger as well.

What should I use to call javascript when:

1. the user refreshes the page,
2. when the user navigates away from the page, or
3. when the user closes the page?

**Edit:** It came up in a comment that I could use a `click()` jQuery handler to detect navigating away. I should have made it more specific that I don't mean when the user clicks a link only then I want it to proc. I want it to trigger when they change pages in any way. So if the address bar gets typed in, for instance.

Comment: Navigate away you could call a function on `$('a').click()`. Or add a class to all external links and call it on those. I thought the unloads would work on refresh and close?

Comment: I will edit my question to include this, since I didn't, but when I said navigate away, I don't mean just with a link. Like if the user types something into the address bar.

Comment: I have a page where I use this: `window.onbeforeunload` and I just checked and it prompts me when I type in the URL, click back, close, or click a link. It fired under ALL your requirements.

Comment: Have you though about using sessions with PHP, instead of doing this with JavaScript? You may want to set a cookie with JavaScript and update it every 10 seconds if their session is active. This would be a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: @Enijar I don't know much about PHP sessions, but I do know about web.py sessions. Is that similar? I could do something like that. Would you have a resource you could point me at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try "onbeforeunload" :

```
window.onbeforeunload
```

But i think you can't put "active" (ajax call) code in this callback function. All you can do is defining a confirm modal window that will be displayed to the user before leaving like :

> Are you sure you want to leave because...

So you should do as @Leeish said : put a code in the .on('click') of the link so it can launch the ajax call before sending to another page.

But for the "refresh" or "close" scenario, you can consider marking your database row as "draft" (or whatever) and if not saved when on the next page, delete the draft line.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked. I guess I was relying on seeing the `alert` popup on the page. Thanks, and thanks to @Leeish! As for the draft part, I will look into it. Would that be something that would be built into the database? Or my web framework? I am using web.py as a backend.

Comment: It depends of your need. You can store temporary value in your session, or in your database if it's more sophisicated